# Como excluir um produto com ID no sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma função que pega o id do produto e este id verifica o produto de um *sessionStorage*. Como que eu faço para ele deletar o produto do id?

```
//dadosdoproduto se refere ao seguinte método    
dadosproduto: [
  {
    "id":"12345",
    "nome":"teste",
    "quantidade":"5",
    "valor":"4"
  },
];

function excluirProdutoStorage (idStorage) {
  var getprodutosArray = sessionStorage.getItem('dadosproduto');
  var parseResult = JSON.parse(getprodutosArray);
  parseResult.forEach(function(item)
  {
    var idProduto = item.idprodutocart;
    if (idProduto == idStorage)
    {
      sessionStorage.removeItem(idProduto);
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: se eu não me engano para remover o item tem que ser com a key dele `removeItem(key)`

Comment: sim mas há vários ids eu queria deletar somente o ID do produto que o cara selecionar e passar na função.

Comment: olha eu sei que no local storage temos uma key e o valor da key, onde o valor no caso é seu json.. se eu fosse remover iria pegar o valor da key e usar a função, por exemplo `minhakey: {"id":"12345", "nome":"teste","quantidade":"5", "valor":"4"}`  `removeItem(minhakey)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Salve o local storage da seguinte maneira
var obj = {
    "dadosproduto": [{
      "id": "01",
      "nome": "nome1",
      "quantidade": "10",
      "valor": "4"
    }, {
      "id": "02",
      "nome": "nome2",
      "quantidade": "20",
      "valor": "5"
    }]
  };

localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj));


/*****************Função para remover******************/
function removeItem(id) {
  var index = -1;
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")) || {}; //localStorage Nome
  var items = obj.dadosproduto || []; //get todos produtos
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { //loop para buscar o id
    if (items[i].id === id) { //verifica id
      items.splice(i, 1); //remove item
      break; //finaliza o loop
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(obj)); //reescreve a localStorage
}

/******************Testes*********************/
console.log(localStorage.cart);
removeItem("01");
console.log(localStorage.cart);
```